# How can I place the <script> tag in <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner in HTML and JavaScript. I want to place `<script>` tag inside `<div>` tag. I want to display **sweet alert tag inside** .

Thanks for advance.

```html
<div id="content">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
        console.log("problem with student");
        swal("You entered the regno more than once", " Your team is not registered yet! Register Again",         "error");
        }
     myFunction();
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: If You using `swal` you need to link it to a page. Via NPM/Yarn or cdn https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

In snippet above, for example, there is error `swal is not defined`. You can fix it by including `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the library via CDN when you are beginer (https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation). Maybe you can use Webpack and installing package via NPM.

This is my hint for your code:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
         console.log("problem with student");
         swal("You entered the regno more than once", " Your team is not registered yet! Register Again",         "error");
      }
      myFunction();
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the value of h5 tags? <h5 th:text="${alreadyRegistered5}" style="color: red"></h5> .I want to get the value of all h5 tags in my code in javascript.

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('h5')].map(x=>x.textContent)`